# Data extract from MQ output issue in perl code

Tags: regex, perl, ibm-mq

I'm having problem with my perl code, the code that I wrote is suppose to grab some information from `MQ` command `dis ql(*) all`,
below is one of the output example from above command,

```
    AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(XXX.DATATYPE.NETSTATVM)           TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2016-08-01)
   ALTTIME(18.33.19)                       BOQNAME( )
   BOTHRESH(0)                             CLUSNL( )
   CLUSTER( )                              CLCHNAME( )
   CLWLPRTY(0)                             CLWLRANK(0)
   CLWLUSEQ(QMGR)                          CRDATE(2016-08-01)
   CRTIME(18.33.19)                        CURDEPTH(0)
   CUSTOM( )                               DEFBIND(OPEN)
   DEFPRTY(0)                              DEFPSIST(YES)
   DEFPRESP(SYNC)                          DEFREADA(NO)
   DEFSOPT(SHARED)                         DEFTYPE(PREDEFINED)
   DESCR(Queue for  XXX.DataType.netstatvm)
   DISTL(NO)                               GET(ENABLED)
   HARDENBO                                INITQ( )
   IPPROCS(1)                              MAXDEPTH(20000)
   MAXMSGL(33554432)                       MONQ(QMGR)
   MSGDLVSQ(PRIORITY)                      NOTRIGGER
   NPMCLASS(NORMAL)                        OPPROCS(0)
   PROCESS( )                              PUT(ENABLED)
   PROPCTL(COMPAT)                         QDEPTHHI(80)
   QDEPTHLO(20)                            QDPHIEV(DISABLED)
   QDPLOEV(DISABLED)                       QDPMAXEV(ENABLED)
   QSVCIEV(NONE)                           QSVCINT(999999999)
   RETINTVL(999999999)                     SCOPE(QMGR)
   SHARE                                   STATQ(QMGR)
   TRIGDATA( )                             TRIGDPTH(1)
   TRIGMPRI(0)                             TRIGTYPE(FIRST)
   USAGE(NORMAL)
```

Above output is grab from one of the queue in `MQ` instead of `all` queue which the command run.

From above, I want to extract the value from `QUEUE`, `CURDEPTH` and `MAXDEPTH`, as below:-

```
QUEUE(XXX.DATATYPE.NETSTATVM)
CURDEPTH(0)
MAXDEPTH(20000)
```

So, I wrote a perl code to obtain the value from `QUEUE`, `CURDEPTH` and `MAXDEPTH`, below is my code,

```
my $qm = XXX;

open (CHS_OUT, "echo 'dis ql(*) all'|runmqsc $qm|");

while (<CHS_OUT>) {
    if ( /QUEUE\(/ ){
        my $QueueName =~ /QUEUE/(/\S+)/g;
    }
    if ( /CURDEPTH\(/ ){
        my $CurDepth =~ s/\D//g;
        chomp $CurDepth;
        print "$CurDepth \n";
    }
    if ( /MAXDEPTH\(/ ){
        my $MaxDepth =~ s/\D//g;
        chomp $MaxDepth;
        print "$MaxDepth \n";
    }
}
```

The output suppose to be as below,

```
XXX.DATATYPE.NETSTATVM
0
20000
```

However, I received a multiple error to extract all of this 3 information, one of the error as below,

> Use of uninitialized value $MaxDepth in substitution (s///) at mq_test.pl line 26,  line 7361.
>       Use of uninitialized value $MaxDepth in scalar chomp at mq_test.pl line 27,  line 7361.
>       Use of uninitialized value $MaxDepth in concatenation (.) or string at mq_test.pl line 28,  line 7361.

This make me confuse since I already do multiples changes of this code but still not success.

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value` These are perl **warnings** not **errors**!

Comment: What is $read? Do you know what `=~` does?

Comment: @AbhiNickz yes, but eventhough I remove the warnings the result still not appear.

Comment: @choroba I forgot to remove that while posting here, will remove it.

Comment: In modern versions of MQ you can use `dmpmqcfg -a -o 1line` to output each object on a single line.  This makes it a lot easier to `grep` out lines of interest, then use `awk` or `cut` to extract the fields of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=~` is the binding operator. It binds the left hand side string to the match on the right hand side. But you have `my $variable` on the LHS - so the string is empty. What you want is to match against the implicit variable, and possibly store a part of the match. This is done by normal assignment in list context:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
    if ( /QUEUE\(/ ) {
        my ($QueueName) = /QUEUE\((\S+)\)/;
        print "QN: $QueueName\n";
    }
    if ( /CURDEPTH\(/ ) {
        my ($CurDepth) = /CURDEPTH\((\d+)/;
        print "CD: $CurDepth\n";
    }
    if ( /MAXDEPTH\(/ ) {
        my ($MaxDepth) = /MAXDEPTH\((\d+)/;
        print "MD: $MaxDepth\n";
    }
}
```

You can combine all the regexes into one, too, and use a hash to store the values keyed by the word before the parenthesis:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %info;
while (<>) {
    if (my ($key, $value)
        = / ( QUEUE | CURDEPTH | MAXDEPTH ) \( ( [^)]+ ) /x
    ) {
        $info{$key} = $value;
    }
}

for my $key (keys %info) {
    print "$key: $info{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct however at the second code which use hash, the output only comes out for the last QUEUE details since it overwrite the others output for each different QUEUE.

Comment: @Azizul: Your input sample only features one QUEUE. You can use a hash of hashes if you want to store the details of multiple queues at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regular Expression

```
(?:QUEUE|CURDEPTH|MAXDEPTH)\(\K[^()]+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XOhFKI/1/).

---

That is

```
(?:QUEUE|CURDEPTH|MAXDEPTH) # one of the alternatives
\(                          # an opening bracket
\K                          # "forget" everything
[^()]+                      # not (), at least once
```

---

In `Perl` this would be:

```
my @matches = $str =~ /(?:QUEUE|CURDEPTH|MAXDEPTH)\(\K[^()]+/g;
print "@matches\n";
# XXX.DATATYPE.NETSTATVM
# 0
# 20000
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to do something similar with awk:

```
echo "DIS QL(*) CURDEPTH MAXDEPTH"|runmqsc $qm | grep -o '^\w\+:\|\w\+[(][^)]\+[)]' | awk -F '[()]' -v OFS='\n' 'function printValues() { if ("QUEUE" in p) { print p["QUEUE"], p["CURDEPTH"], p["MAXDEPTH"], "" } } /^\w+:/ { printValues(); delete p; next } { p[$1] = $2 } END { printValues() }'
```

Output would look like this:

```
XXX.DATATYPE.NETSTATVM
0
20000

YYY.DATATYPE.NETSTATVM
50
10000
```